# Haskell ~ Does last iterate the entire list?

Tags: list, haskell

Simple question for Haskellites: Does Haskell iterate an entire sequence to obtain the last value? Specifically, are a different number of instructions executed for these two expressions?

```
Prelude> last "asdf"
'f'
Prelude> last "qwerty"
'y'
```

Comment: BTW, if you expect to call "last" often, there would exist other data structures you can use (instead of a list/string) in which that operation is faster than traversing the entire list.

Comment: In particular, following ShreevatsaR, Data.Sequence, in the containers library, provides a "finger tree", with O(1) access to the last element.

Comment: You can find out yourself by looking at the definition.  To find the definition hoogle for "last" and click on the "source" link in the documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, Haskell's list are singly linked and thus `last` needs to walk through the entire list, making its runtime `O(n)`.

Comment: @sepp2k: Considering how plainly correct this answer is, my best guess is somebody on an iPhone who fat-fingered an upvote.

Comment: Because gdi's answer encouraged an experiment to determine the answer instead of just saying it.

Comment: @luqui: Encouraging him to read the source, I might have understood, but "conducting experiments" is not a good way to determine a function's running time and I don't think it's something that should be encouraged. It's basically encouraging people to just accept things without understanding them. First of all trying something out and seeing that it takes longer for larger arguments is hardly proof that a function takes `O(n)` time. Second of all trying it out and seeing that it takes longer, does not explain *why* it takes longer (which saying Haskell lists are singly linked does).

Comment: @sepp2k, I treat SO as an educational site -- after all, people come here to learn (very specific) things.  I usually support answers that coincide with how I would treat a student.  And I would encourage the student to experiment instead of telling him the answer.   I acknowledge that the assumption that SO askers should be treated as students is not universal (just give them the damn info already) -- and to those who disagree, it's fortunate that I have merely one vote with which to express my values.

Comment: @luqui: As I said, I could understand it if you said "read the source", but any professor (or TA or other educator) who answered "try it out and see how long it takes" when asked "what is the running time complexity of this function?" isn't doing a very good job IMHO.

Comment: @sepp2k, I support scientific methods in programming just as much as mathematical ones.  We seem to differ on this value.  And to any challenge of "that's not scientific", I respond http://xkcd.com/397/ .

Comment: sepp2k is right insofar as a determination that "it takes longer on longer sequences" does not yield a conclusion of O(n) time.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what sepp2k said, this is easy to determine: simply run "last [1..1000000000]" and see if it takes awhile. As expected, it does.

Answer (score 3):

As the other two answers have said: yes, last is an O(n) operations on standard lists. If you are dealing with textual data, you can consider using the [text package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) which provides an O(1) [last function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.0.1/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy.html#v%3alast). If you are *not* dealing with text data, you can look into the bytestring or vector packages.